# Wordpress add new record custom admin.php not working

Tags: wordpress

I have some custom wordpress migration, where there are a few custom plug-ins.

The problem which I am facing is that I have add new team member as link the folling link:

```
<a href="admin.php?page=wb_team_list&amp;action=edit" class="button add-new-h2">Add New</a>
```

so when I press that button I am getting the form but no input fields are presented.

[image]

The question is more of where to be looking in order to resolve this, since it is using admin.php wordpress functionality? Any suggestion or guidance will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late answer but...

Some key guidance is given in [Admin Screen Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Admin_Screen_Reference). See:

```
Top level pages admin.php?page={page_slug}  toplevel_page_{page_slug}
Sub pages       admin.php?page={page_slug}  {parent_slug}_page_{page_slug}
```

So, you are working with either a (top) menu page or a sub menu page.

You need to search for calls to `add_menu_page()` and `add_submenu_page()` that pass `wb_team_list` as `$menu_slug`. The `$function` passed in the function call generates the page content.

(The answer was verified against the theme I am currently working with.)